# Create more padding-left xAxis + chart. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can I configure Highcharts to push both the chart area + xAxis ticks and labels to make room for the yAxis labels?

[image: padding issue]

Comment: What you're asking for happens by default. Set up a fiddle that replicates this problem so that we can see what options are causing it.

Comment: You can look at your chart.marginLeft and chart.spacingLeft parameters, they may cause the issue.